# Validation Rule: Multiple combines into one rule

Tags: validation-rule, validation

I have three similar validation rule which I'm trying to make it into a single one: My field is a Percent

my three different validation rules are:

1.
OR(
field1__c + field2__c > 1.0
)

2.
OR(
ISBLANK(field1__c),
ISBLANK(field2__c)
)

3.
OR(
field1__c < 0 ,
field2__c < 0
)

I have tried something like this:

```
AND(
    field1__c + field2__c > 1.0,
    OR( 
        ISBLANK(field1__c),
        ISBLANK(field2__c)
    ),
    OR( 
        field1__c < 0,
        field2__c < 0
    )
)
```

I can still be able to save the record with empty

Answer (score 0):

Remember that validation rules fire when the result is true (making *invalidation* rule a better term for them).

If *any* of your 3 base conditions are true, the validation rule should fire.

Meaning you should wrap the entire thing in an `OR()` instead of an `AND()`. You could get rid of the inner `OR()` functions and just have all 5 conditions in one big `OR()`, but breaking them out like you have shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: i was so close :)